# How to draw these triangles in C# and save the result in BMP image format?

Tags: c#, system.drawing

[What i need to draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5efq.png)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int triangleSize = int.Parse(args[0]);
        int depth = int.Parse(args[1]);
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        DrawTriangle(triangleSize, depth, image, 250, 250);
        image.Save("triangles.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }

    static void DrawTriangle(int triangleSize, int depth, Bitmap image, int x, int y)
    {
        if (depth == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        int triangleHeight = (int)(triangleSize * Math.Sin(Math.PI / 3));
        Point[] points = new Point[]
        {
            new Point(x, y),
            new Point(x + triangleSize - 1, y + triangleHeight),
            new Point(x - triangleSize + 1, y + triangleHeight)
        };

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Black, points);
        }

        DrawTriangle(triangleSize / 2, depth - 1, image, x, y + triangleHeight / 2);
        DrawTriangle(triangleSize / 2, depth - 1, image, x + triangleSize / 4, y - triangleHeight / 4);
        DrawTriangle(triangleSize / 2, depth - 1, image, x - triangleSize / 4, y - triangleHeight / 4);
    }
}
```

The most i got was drawing(?) the first 2 parts but it this error -" System.Drawing.Common 7.0.0 doesn't support netcoreapp3.0 and has not been tested with it.".  And I am at a loss what to do?

Comment: Try retargeting your project to use the .NET 6 or 7 Windows SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You could try targeting .NET 6 or 7 Windows. Or you could downgrade the System.Drawing.Common package. You currently are using 7.0.0. When you downgrade to 5.0.3 .NET 3.0 is supported. You could also choose to upgrade the application to .NET 3.1 and use System.Drawing.Common at 6.0.0.